# Как преобразовать программу на perl в откомпилированный исполняемый файл?

Tags: perl

У меня есть код перл. Как преобразовать его в откомпилированный исполняемый файл? С помощью какой программы это делается?

Answer (score 1):

[perl2exe](http://www.indigostar.com/perl2exe.php), например. Но мне подобные штуки не по душе.

Comment: Увы код не могу скинуть... посколку он уникальный.

Comment: любой Perl`овский код уникален=)

Comment: А зачем куда-то кидать уникальный код? Возьми указанную программу и попробуй ею скомпилировать уникальный экзешник.

Answer (score 0):

Программой pp из Par::Packer'а. Она соберет один большой файл, в который будет встроен perl'овый интерпретатор и все зависимые модули вашей программы.

Answer (score 0):

из штатного perlcc в *nix, но глючный)) может и винде есть..

Comment: Мне вообще все эти "переводчики" из языка в язык не нравятся. Почти всегда проблемы. Код, даже если работает, совершенно монстроподобный, медленный. Уж если нужен исполняемый файл, переписать программу на соответственном языке.

Comment: perlcc дает совершенно обычный бинарный исполняемый код.. Другое дело, что perl для этого не особо создан и будет куча ограничений

Answer (score 0):

Cava::Packager еще из неплохо работающих.
Но идея тухлая, ведь туда влезет всё, включая интерпретатор и модули.